# Condition on singular values of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, singular-values, linear-matrix-inequality

For symmetric matrices $M$ and $N$, it is easy to verify that $\sigma_{max}(M)\leq\sigma_{min}(N)$ is a sufficient condition for $M\leq N$, where $\sigma_{max}(.)$ and $\sigma_{min}(.)$ denote the maximum and minimum singular values.

I wanted to prove if it is also a necessary condition.

In other words, is it true that $M\leq N$ if and only if $\sigma_{max}(M)\leq\sigma_{min}(N)$?

Comment: have you tried working through examples of $2\times 2$ diagonal matrices?

Comment: It is not even a sufficient condition unless we are given more information (e.g. that $M$ and $N$ are positive definite). For example, 
$$
M = \pmatrix{-1 & 0\\0 & -1}, \quad N = \pmatrix{-2 & 0\\0 & -2}
$$
satisfy $\sigma_{\max}(M) \leq \sigma_{\min}(N)$ but not $M \leq N$.

Comment: It is also not a necessary condition. For example, consider
$$
M = \pmatrix{1\\ &3}, \quad N = \pmatrix{2\\ & 4}.
$$

Comment: @user9 By the way, please clarify what you mean by $M \geq N$. I am guessing that you are referring to the [Loewner order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order), but this notation is ambiguous and bears clarification.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the asker mixed up eigenvalues with singular values. Then one way holds as $M\le \sigma_{\max}(M)\,I\le \sigma_{\min}(N)\,I \le N.$